# building android-ndk?

Tags: android-ndk

I want to build an off-line speech recognition application for android.For that i tried building android NDK.But when i give ndk-build command i get the following error.I have no idea what that means as i am very new to Linux environment..Anyone please help me.

```
 Android NDK: Could not find application project directory !    
    Android NDK: Please define the NDK_PROJECT_PATH variable to point to it.    
    /home/cenuser/android/android-ndk-r7b/build/core/build-local.mk:130: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
```

and when i changed the location to i got this

```
/home/cenuser/android/sphinx/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:760:26: error: pocketsphinx.h: No such file or directory
/home/cenuser/android/sphinx/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:761:28: error: sphinxbase/err.h: No such file or directory
/home/cenuser/android/sphinx/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c: In function 'new_Hypothesis':
/home/cenuser/android/sphinx/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:780: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
/home/cenuser/android/sphinx/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:782: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
/home/cenuser/android/sphinx/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:784: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
/home/cenuser/android/sphinx/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c: In function 'new_Config__SWIG_0':
/home/cenuser/android/sphinx/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:795: error: 'FALSE' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/cenuser/android/sphinx/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:795: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/home/cenuser/android/sphinx/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:795: error: for each function it appears in.)
/home/cenuser/android/sphinx/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c: In function 'new_Config__SWIG_1':
/home/cenuser/android/sphinx/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:799: error: 'FALSE' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/cenuser/android/sphinx/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c: In function 'Config_getString':
/home/cenuser/android/sphinx/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:830: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast
/home/cenuser/android/sphinx/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c: In function 'new_Decoder__SWIG_0':
/home/cenuser/android/sphinx/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:839: error: 'FALSE' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/cenuser/android/sphinx/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c: In function 'new_Decoder__SWIG_1':
/home/cenuser/android/sphinx/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:843: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
/home/cenuser/android/sphinx/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c: In function 'Decoder_getConfig':
/home/cenuser/android/sphinx/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:847: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast
/home/cenuser/android/sphinx/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c: In function 'Decoder_getUttid':
/home/cenuser/android/sphinx/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:856: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast
/home/cenuser/android/sphinx/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c: In function 'Decoder_getHyp':
/home/cenuser/android/sphinx/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:869: error: 'int32' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/cenuser/android/sphinx/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:869: error: expected ';' before 'best_score'
/home/cenuser/android/sphinx/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:870: error: 'best_score' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/cenuser/android/sphinx/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c: In function 'Java_edu_cmu_pocketsphinx_pocketsphinxJNI_Decoder_1processRaw_1_1SWIG_10':
/home/cenuser/android/sphinx/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:1441: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
make: *** [/home/cenuser/android/sphinx/PocketSphinxDemo/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/pocketsphinx_jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 16):

1. Go to the ndk root folder from terminal
2. Type the command with your project path

   ```
   ndk-build -C your_project_path
   ```

This will solve the problem. If you want more information on "ndk-build" command just type the command

```
    ndk-build --help
```

Answer (score 9):

This usually happens when you invoke ndk-build from incorrect diretory. You must be in folder which contains jni subdirectory.

Or alternatively do what error message tells you - specify NDK_PROJECT_PATH to correct folder.

Comment: NDK_PROJECT_PATH=/home/cenuser/android/sphinx/PocketSphinxDemo export=NDK_PROJECT_PATH are defined

Answer (score 3):

you need to declare the path to the location while running the ndk-build command
1. cd 
2. ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to /build/core
2. Change the NDK_PROJECT_PATH to app project path
3. Open terminal
4. Go to Project folder
5. Run the NDK_BUILD

Answer (score 0):

This could be solves as follows: 
I have faced the same problem. I was working on an text recognition application.

```
1- You should go the directory of your folder (which is inside the AndroidStudioProjects - "YOUR PROJECT", 

2- There should be a jni (Java Native interface) folder. Search for this folder. whenever, this is found. 

3- cd in cmd to that folder (The Parent folder of jni).

4- run **ndk-build**
```